# How to export a circle line as path instead of circle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path

I'm new to AI and been struggling to get a circle exported as path instead of circle. I need path for animation on web.
The shape is really simple, just a 1pt line circle. I used arc tools and joined 4 arcs together to make the shape.

Comment: Use the circle tool.  A circle made with the circle tool is a single path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your circle, go to **object** menu -> **compound path** and press **make**.

In your SVG output, your circle shape will convert to svg path.